# How to make a CSS table with use of DIV UL LI

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-tables

Imagine, I have DIV container, 9 `<ul>` tags inside of it (they are columns), each `<ul>` tag has 5 `<li>` tags inside and each `<li>` tag has one link inside.

I want to make it pure CSS kind of a table where all `<ul>` widths would not need to have a hard width set, but vary and auto stretch relative to the lenght of links in `<li>` tags and in relation to the other `<ul>` tags, so some colums will be wider, some will be shorter if the links in them are long or short.

Can you help me with that? I was trying to make that and everything worked except the auto stretching `<ul>` tags, they had fixed widths :(

Comment: It kinda sounds like you need a `table` here. What's the reason you want to juryrig these other tags instead?

Comment: look into display:table and related CSS

Comment: Andrew, all of my other code is pure css, i don't want to put HTML table there

Comment: `<div>` `<ul>` and `<li>` are **not** CSS. They are HTML. You use the correct, semantic HTML for what your content is, then you use CSS to style it. You are specifically trying to use the *incorrect* HTML, and then trying to use CSS as a heavy kludge to do styling that would be much easier if you started from the proper tag. `<table>` tags are *fine* to use - as long as you use them properly.

Comment: @CamSpy religiously avoiding tables is just as bad as misusing them. It clearly shows you have no idea of what you're doing but you have a strong opinion about it. I even guess which document you've read to get this idea and I can tell you the document is badly justified rant at best. And there is nothing called pure css or css table. It's a myth coined in by purists with a religous attitude. How do you think DIV/UL/LI with tons of hacking is better than TABLE/TR/TD with no hacking? You want a table? Guess what, they lied to you, tables aren't bad, use `<table>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a table from ul tag using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892807/how-to-make-a-table-from-ul-tag-using-css)

Comment: @TylerH - my question is almost 1.5 years older than the one you were pointing at. What's the point of doing that?

Comment: @CamSpy Your post came up on the active questions list because Brian Tompsett edited it. I felt there was definitely another question on the site with more and better answers, and I was right. Age of questions is only a minor (and easily-trumped) factor in determining the target for a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey i have a solution for you from what i can make out that you need here...

http://jsfiddle.net/YPmtG/4/

I am basically just floating the ul's and the li's are naturally hosted inside the ul so they can be individually floated inside there again as shown in my fiddle...

```
ul {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    padding:5px;
}
li {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the div container with fixed width and ul tags should auto stretch to the width of container